# Sub-make does not expand target specific variables

Tags: makefile

Give the following example makefile:

```
export MY_COMMENT  := 'Hello world'

t1: MY_COMMENT += 'very much!'
t1:
    @echo $(MY_COMMENT)

t2: MY_COMMENT += 'and I love you all'
t2:
    @$(MAKE) -e --no-print-directory t1
```

If on the command line, I type `make t2`, the expected output was:

```
Hello world and I love you all very much!
```

Instead I get:

```
Hello world and I love you all
```

What am I missing in order to have the target specific variable for `t1` be exported as well or appended to the variable `MY_COMMENT`?

---

I also realise I could make `t2` depend on `t1` which will solve that immediate issue, but when answering, assume I cannot have `t2` depend on `t1` and I need to call `make` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `override` for each target specific variable. So I ended up with:

```
export MY_COMMENT  := 'Hello world'

t1: override MY_COMMENT += 'very much!'
t1:
    @echo $(MY_COMMENT)

t2: override MY_COMMENT += 'and I love you all'
t2:
    @$(MAKE) -e --no-print-directory t1
```

And this now gives the correct outpuit